# to retrieve a Japanese or localized string from a file

Tags: powershell

I have the below code to retrieve a Japanese or localized string from an mht file. i have used almost all the encoding params listed here(unknown,string,unicode,bigendianunicode,utf8,utf7,utf32,ascii,default,oem) and verified. it always prints the junk characters instead of original Chinese or Japanese name

```
$log = "c:\scripts\meta.mht"
$patt = 'title'
$indx = Select-String $patt $log | ForEach-Object {$_.LineNumber}
write-host (Get-Content $log)[$indx] | out-file -encoding string c:\scripts\temp1.xml
```

can some one help me how to print the localized string? which encoding param should i use?
i have tried with all the listed params but no luck (unknown,string,unicode,bigendianunicode,utf8,utf7,utf32,ascii,default,oem)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your encoding for `Get-Content` like this:

```
write-host (Get-Content -Path $log -Encoding UTF8)[$indx] | out-file -encoding UTF8 c:\scripts\temp1.xml
```

I'm not sure if you'll need UTF8 or UNICODE, try both for `Get-Content` and `Out-File`.

Comment: I am very happy with this solution...it works perfect. but i have a question does UTF8 supports all localized languages strings. in future, i am going to use around 104 localized languages.

Comment: @jakkpraveen You should be fine going forward with UTF8. It can encode any unicode character. Check out this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#General) for more info. BTW - Glad this help you, since this answered your question please accept it as the accepted answer. Thanks.